# Launch app through Siri with parameters, without donations/shortcuts

Tags: ios, parameters, ios13, siri, sirishortcuts

Suppose I'm making an app that a user can install several little interactive experiences (*meditations*) onto.

For convenience, I'd like my users to be able to start one by saying: *“Hey Siri, start **Beach Sunset** in Meditations.”*

Because of reasons, it makes sense for users to perform this action by voice, *without* ever first having interacted with *Beach Sunset* in the iOS app. (They may for example already “own” it through my service's web app.)

That is to say: I want a voice action like *“Hey Siri, start Beach Sunset in Meditations”* to work even *without* the user setting up a Shortcut for it first, or me “donating” actions for it.

Is that possible? (I feel like many of the default apps expose similar behavior, but maybe they're special.) If not, what is the next best thing I can do?

Are "donations" necessary for Siri to be aware of my app's voice actions, or are they simply a mechanism for hinting and predicting user behavior?

Are "shortcuts" necessary for Siri to be aware of my app's voice actions, or are they simply a mechanism for user phrase customization?

> I've never added Siri support to an iOS app, but it seems “parameters” have gotten a lot more powerful in iOS 13. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029795/how-can-i-utilize-siri-to-create-a-custom-object-without-donating-intents-or-usi) suggests something similar wasn't possible in iOS 12, but I think it's also doing something somewhat different (I want to launch the app; they want to “create an object” presumably just using Intent UI. I don't know if this matters.)

### What I've done

I've defined a custom intent in the *Start* category (`LaunchMeditation`) with a single parameter (`meditationName`).

I considered the standard *Media* intents, but the media here is interactive and not strictly audio/video, and I don't want to get in trouble.

I've added an Intents Extension to my app, and written a rudimentary test "handler" that just tries to pass the meditation name on to the app:

```c
@interface IntentHandler () <LaunchMeditationIntentHandling>
@end

@implementation IntentHandler
- (id)handlerForIntent:(INIntent *)intent { return self; }

- (void)handleLaunchMeditation:(nonnull LaunchMeditationIntent *)intent
                    completion:(nonnull void (^)(LaunchMeditationIntentResponse * _Nonnull))completion {
  // XXX: Maybe activity can just be nil?
  NSUserActivity *activity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:@"com.example.meditations.activity.launch"];
  activity.title           = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Launch %@ in Meditations", intent.meditationName]; // Do I need this?
  activity.userInfo        = @{@"meditationName": intent.meditationName};
  completion([[LaunchMeditationIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:LaunchMeditationIntentResponseCodeContinueInApp
                                                     userActivity:activity]);
}

- (void)resolveMeditationNameForLaunchMeditation:(nonnull LaunchMeditationIntent *)intent
                                  withCompletion:(nonnull void (^)(INStringResolutionResult * _Nonnull))completion {
  completion([INStringResolutionResult successWithResolvedString:intent.meditationName]);
}
@end
```

When I test the Intents Extension, I can now make a Shortcut for it in Shortcuts, set its parameter, give it a name (like “Beach time”), and launch it by telling Siri that name — which is everything I *don't* want users to have to do.

Other than that, Siri responds with

> Meditations hasn't added support for that with Siri.

…no matter how I phrase my request to start *Beach Sunset*. That *“hasn't added support”* sounds agonizingly much like there's simply something I'm missing.

Comment: Have you had any success? It feels like it should be supported to just add Siri support via system/custom intents and not donate anything to the system. A podcasts app can also resolve "play podcast <podcast title> in <podcast app name>" without having to donate every podcast first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try to briefly answer all of your questions.

- You can't create a Siri action without donating actions. Once you donate your actions they are not registered to Siri either. Users must create a Shortcut to be able to use them.
- The next best thing you can do is to inform your users about your Siri Shortcuts. To do this you can show a pop-up or inform your new users on onboarding screens. The good part is you can redirect your users to the "Creating Siri Shortcut" screen via this code which you can trigger by button click or tap gesture.

```
let shortcut = INShortcut(userActivity: shortcutActivity!) // shortcutActivity is your donated activity.          
let vc = INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController(shortcut: shortcut)
vc.delegate = self // INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewControllerDelegate
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

- Shortcuts are necessary for Siri to be aware of you implementation.
- As far as I know intent domains help you specify more parameters for your Siri shortcuts. Which enables you to create more Siri interactions.
- Apple also promotes Siri Shortcuts of commonly used apps. If your users are using your app in a regular basis or more often than others they might see a Siri Shortcut Suggestion in their home screen. Similar to this [one](https://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Siri-Suggested-shortcuts-iPhone-Lock-screen-hero-002.jpg).

I also think it would be great to donate Siri Shortcuts without any user action but there would be certain problems such as:

- What if two or more different apps uses the same phrase for a Siri Shortcut?
- How will Siri distinguish an unregistered command from a simple conversation? For example if someone created a shortcut with the phrase "Hi Siri".
- Even if you donate an action with a certain phrase Siri must learn how it's user pronounces that certain phrase.

These may cause a lot of harm than good thus I think Apple choose the current way. Hope these answers your questions.

Comment: I think you comment was before appIntents (iOS16).  Would this have changed the answer?